# What's the New SDK equivalent to FB.Facebook.get_isInCanvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Trying to find the new Facebook javascript sdk equivalent to:

```
FB.Facebook.get_isInCanvas
```

Is there a PHP SDK way of this call as well?

I need to test if inside the canvas, and header checks and signed_request checks do not determine if user is on Facebook within the Application...unless I don't have the right way of checking...

Answer (score 1):

`FB._inCanvas` is what you want from the Facebook JS SDK however that i found is sometimes not always set so lets see how they themselves do the check and copy that:

```
var _inCanvas: (
  (window.location.search.indexOf('fb_sig_in_iframe=1') > -1) ||
  (window.location.search.indexOf('session=') > -1)
);
```

See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/blob/master/src/core/prelude.js#L71

**UPDATE**
The newer version of this is:

```
((window.location.search.indexOf('fb_sig_in_iframe=1')>-1)||
(window.location.search.indexOf('session=')>-1) ||
(window.location.search.indexOf('signed_request=')>-1) ||
(window.name.indexOf('iframe_canvas')>-1) ||
(window.name.indexOf('app_runner')>-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP-SDK you can assume application running in canvas if you have `signed_request` in your `$_REQUEST`/`$_POST`. Not fully safe but may be ok to assume it in most cases...

JS-SDK can say that it's not running in canvas for sure only by checking `window.top == window` not very useful if you need to know you're in canvas and not just someone's frame.

**Update:**
Just checked and there is a better option in JS-SDK to check if you running in canvas but I'm not sure this behavior wouldn't change in future. You can use something like this:

```
var pageInfo = FB.Canvas.getPageInfo();
var isInCanvas = (pageInfo && pageInfo.clientWidth == 0);
```

Comment: As for the PHP SDK, I'm getting the signed_request parameter returned when I'm both inside the application on Facebook, and outside of it, just visiting the website in a new tab.  Using $facebook->getSignedRequest() works outside of Facebook as long as you've logged into the App on a separate tab.... so how do I check via PHP that the user is inside of the Facebook Canvas?

Comment: I could use $_REQUEST, but then it drops from page to page.  I could store it as a Session variable, but then if a user opened the webpage outside of the app in a new tab, the session would still be valid.  How come there is not a simple check to see if your inside the canvas?

Comment: `$_REQUEST` will be in most cases populated by `signed_request` from `$_COOKIES` depending on your php settings. `$_POST` is safer here. It will be always populated in canvas

Comment: $_POST['signed_request'] drops when I navigate to a different page in my app, as does request.  I don't have to pass it in EVERY link do I?  There's got to be a more efficient way...

Comment: I personally use several techniques depending on needs: 1. link with `target="_top"`; 2. using ajax with POST request which includes `signed_request` "passed to original page"/"retrieved from JS-SDK"; 3. Submitting regular/hidden form with `signed_request` as one of `type="hidden"` inputs. Those methods always pass me signed_request on every page in my apps